# If $P(u,v|x,y)=P(u|x)P(v|x)$, does it follow that $P(x,y|u,v) = P(x|u)P(y|v)$?

Tags: correlation, independence

Let $u,v,x,y$ be four random variables such that:

$$P(u,v|x,y)=P(u|x)P(v|x)$$

The question is: Does it follow that

$$P(x,y|u,v) = P(x|u)P(y|v)$$?

Comment: Why are you only conditioning u on x and v on y? The title question would suggest that your first line should be P(u,v|x,y) = P(u|x,y).P(v|x,y); similarly for the second equation. Why do you drop some terms from the conditioning?

Comment: @Glen_b I made the title more precise. This is not for a class, it's a question I came up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Indeed I see no reason why you'd even suspect it to be the case.

Here's a trivial counterexample.

Consider $U$ and $V$ each independent of all other variables, and further consider $X$ and $Y$ as being dependent (correlated, say), but independent of $U$ and $V$.

Then the first condition is true but the second is not.